# Are java annotation lists supposed to allow an extra comma after the last entry?

Tags: java, annotations

I accidentally left an extra comma at the end of one of my annotation lists, but it compiled fine on my machine. For example:

`@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name="name1",query="FROM Foo"),
        @NamedQuery(name="name2",query="FROM Bar"),
    })`

Notice the extra comma after the second @NamedQuery. It seems to compile fine on my machine, but someone else had problems compiling the code on their machine, so I removed it. But I am now curious as to whether it's supposed to be allowed, and if so, what version of java allows it.

I have not been able to find any reference to this anywhere online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in this case you're dealing with [Array Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6) that allow the extra comma.

Example:

```
int[] foo = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, };
```

This has been part of the JLS from the beginning.

Comment: > A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is ignored. (+1)

Comment: The Java Language Specification explicitly allows a trailing comma in Annotation Arrays (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7). However there seems to be a bug in javac that throws an error ("illegal start of expression"). So to be on the safe side you should not use trailing commas in annotations, while they are quite ok in array initializers.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this will work in some annotation processing contexts and not in others. If you're using Sun's command-line APT, it will cause a nasty error. (It works fine in eclipse, though)